# MySQL select child table as list

Tags: mysql

I'm working with MariaDB, I'm very new at SQL so I'm struggling with the concept of parent and child table. This is what I need:

1. A menu with all the dish offered by the restaurant
2. Each dish has his ingredients, maybe some dish has no ingredients and the same ingredient can be used in different dishes
3. I want (if possible) an SQL query that returns all the dishes, each containing his own ingredients in a list or something
4. If this is not possible I can do it in PHP but what is the best way to get those data to PHP?

I have no idea how the query should be but I have two possible database setup:

In both this is the menu I refer to

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | pizza   |
|  2 | pasta   |
|  3 | caprese |
+----+---------+
```

Method 1 with 2 tables:

```
+-------------------+---------+
| name              | id_dish |
+-------------------+---------+
| tomato            |       1 |
| mozzarella cheese |       1 |
| tomato            |       3 |
| mozzarella cheese |       3 |
| basil             |       1 |
+-------------------+---------+
```

Where id_dish is a foreign key referring to the id column in the menu.

The problem here is that if I have 10 same ingredients I have to repeat the same ingredient (and in the future all his properties) 10 times and sounds redundant.

Method 2 with 3 tables:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | name              |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | tomato            |
|  2 | mozzarella cheese |
|  3 | basil             |
+----+-------------------+

+---------+---------------+
| id_dish | id_ingredient |
+---------+---------------+
|       1 |             1 |
|       1 |             2 |
|       1 |             3 |
|       3 |             1 |
|       3 |             2 |
+---------+---------------+
```

Where both those two columns are foreign key referring to the menu and the ingredients.

I think this is more complicated but is the most efficient way, tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The second way is the proper way. This is called database normalization.

Comment: Any class on relational database design should cover it.

Comment: Thanks but I can't really find something like what I'm asking in the step 3, I think is different from `INNER JOIN` that is everything I found about this topic

Comment: Step 3 is a many-to-many relationship table, it's common in many databases.

Comment: To get the list of ingrediants for a dish, you simply use two INNER JOIN. Join dish to dish_ingredients and join dish_ingredients to ingredients.

Comment: Ok but I'm trying to avoid making 100 different query to get the ingredients of 100 dishes, I believe this isn't good for performance. Is there a way to get all ingredients at once but already separated in lists (one for each dish) or I have to do it in PHP?

Comment: Why would you need 100 differnt queries? You can get them all in a single query.

Comment: If you want the ingredients in a single list, use `GROUP_CONCAT()` along with `GROUP BY dish_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the last method, and use `GROUP BY` to get all the ingredients for each dish.

```
SELECT dish.name, GROUP_CONCAT(ingredient.name) AS ingredients
FROM dish 
JOIN dish_ingredient ON dish.id = dish_ingredient.dish_id
JOIN ingredient ON ingredient.id = dish_ingredient.ingredient_id
GROUP BY dish.id
```

Comment: For the people reading this: in order to get all the dishes (also the ones with no ingredients) I had to replace both the `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: of course. I just didn't imagine you could have dishes with no ingredients, they would be quite bland.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct way. If you would like to change one of the ingredients you should search in whole table and change name of many rows. In your solution you can change only name in one row.

If you want to get all ingredients from one dish you make select with joins.

```
SELECT ingredients.name FROM menu LEFT JOIN ingredients_menu ON menu.id=ingredients_menu.id_dish LEFT JOIN ingredients ON ingredients_menu.id_ingredient=ingredients.id WHERE menu.id = 'pizza';
```